# RxSwift - Verifying if text field is focused

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

I have a `UITextField` and would like to perform an action everytime it's focused. Is this something that RxSwift can manage or I would have to do so in the old way?

Comment: What about `textField.rx.controlEvent(UIControlEvents)`?

Comment: I saw something about it but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

After some hours researching, I saw [this issue on their GitHub page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1228) and made it work through that.

Turns out my code was:

```
txtDate
    .rx
    .controlEvent(UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    .map{ true }
    .bind(to: txtDateHasFocused).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

That didn't generate any reactivity at all. Unfortunately I don't know why. The correct way to check if a `UITextField` is focused (or being edited) is:

```
txtDate
    .rx
    .controlEvent(UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin) // Here is the key
    .map{ true }
    .bind(to: txtDateHasFocused).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Turns out that the `UIControlEvent` I was using was wrong, again, I don't know why. Maybe is related to the responders on iOS. An explanation about "why .touchUpInside does not trigger events in this case" would be great.